# Finding Invariant Subspaces without Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

How can I find invariant subspaces of a particular matrix A=$\begin{pmatrix}1&3 \\ 1 &-1\end{pmatrix}$ without using any concepts of eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

I've already found that {0}, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are invariant subspaces. But I have no clue how to go about finding the invariant subspaces with dimension 1.

Comment: Finding one-dimensional invariant subspaces is precisely one of the motivations behind the idea of eigenvectors and eigenvalues. They are a way to answer the question “which lines (through the origin) are mapped onto themselves?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve for a non-zero   $V$ in $$AV=\lambda V$$

The same idea of finding eigen-vectors. I found two vectors, $$\binom {1}{1/3}$$  and $$\binom {1}{-1}$$

So the span of each vector gives you a one dimensional invariant subspace.